# Cache file for an hour in Javascript

Tags: javascript, caching, bookmarklet

I'm creating a bookmarklet that loads an external script like so:

```
script.setAttribute('src', 'http://scriptsrc.com');
```

I added cache-busting to that so that if I update the script it loads, all users immediately get the update and nothing unexpected happens.

```
script.setAttribute('src', 'http://scriptsrc.com?' + new Date().getTime());
```

Because I expect users will be clicking on this bookmarklet a lot, I was thinking some local caching is a good thing, so my question is how would you ensure that the file isis only held in the cache for about an hour? I was thinking something along these lines might work

```
script.setAttribute('src', 'http://scriptsrc.com?' + (new Date().getTime()).toString().substring(0,7));
```

because we're approximately grabbing down to the 7th value in that number that would change on the hour (I think). I'm bad at math, and there might be a better way to do this though.

Thanks!

Comment: The browser already caches script files.  This is not something you have to implement yourself.

Comment: yes, unless the user has disabled the ability, local caching is already handled by the browser
(alternatively, why not either make a really long bookmarklet, or make a userscript)

Comment: The question is about busting the cached file after an hour. I'll update the question to be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do exactly what you asked is this: `(new Date()).getHours()`

I don't see anything fundamentally terrible about doing this, but you'd be better off in the long run learning a bit about how browser caching works.